# If cells in a range blank... then blank... otherwise CONCATENATE

Tags: excel

So here is a picture to help clarify what I mean:

Concatenating empty cells leave a `,`, so I wanted to change the formula so that if a cell is blank in range `J2:P2`, then leave blank. Otherwise `CONCATENATE` the email addresses.

What is a good way about this?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: can you show your current formula?

Comment: Sure: `=CONCATENATE(G3,", 
",H3,", 
",I3,", 
",J3,", 
",K3,", 
",L3,", 
",M3,", 
",N3,", 
",O3)`

Comment: you can use something like this `=J2 & IF(J2="","",", ") & K2 & IF(K2="","",", ")& L2 & IF(L2="","",", ") & ...  & N2 & IF(N2="","",", ") & O2`. Not sure there is more effifcient way using only formulas

Comment: the slickest way to do this may be with a VBA function that takes the range required and returns the concatenated fields, however it would also be possible with lots of if statements within your concatenate. Do you have a preference between using pure Excel functions or getting the VBA for a bespoke function?

Comment: Granted, I have never really used VBA (I know what it is). However I am willing to try new methods if they are more efficient. :)

Comment: @simoco, the only issue with the formula you gave is that it leaves one comma ( still a lot better than before) at the end.

Comment: use `=J2 & IF(J2="","",", ") & K2 & IF(K2="","",", ")& L2 & IF(L2="","",", ") & ...  & N2 & IF(N2="","",", ") & O2` - note that there is no last `& IF(O2="","",", ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Non VBA solution**

use

```
=J2 & IF(J2="","",", ") & K2 & IF(K2="","",", ") & L2 & IF(L2="","",", ") & M2 & IF(M2="","",", ")  & N2 & IF(N2="","",", ") & O2
```

note that there is no last `& IF(O2="","",", ")`

**VBA solution**

For bigger ranges using VBA would be simplier. Add this UDF:

```
Function conc(r As Range) As String
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In r
        If c.Value <> "" Then conc = conc & c.Value & ", "
    Next
    If Len(conc) > 0 Then conc = Left(Trim(conc), Len(Trim(conc)) - 1)
End Function
```

and then call it like this: `=conc(J2:O2)`.

---

For adding UDF press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, create new module and paste code into it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I'm eventually going to export the .xls into a CSV. Will VBA functions transfer over as just plain text when it is exported into a CSV file?

Comment: if you would use UDF in xls file and then save this file as CSV, it would save just result of concatenation (plain text)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid extra commas when, for example, only J2 and L2 are populated try concatenating `<comma><space>` to the **start** of each cell value....then use REPLACE to get rid of the extra one you don't need at the start, i.e.

`=REPLACE(IF(J2="","",", "&J2)&IF(K2="","",", "&K2)&IF(L2="","",", "&L2)&IF(M2="","",", "&M2)&IF(N2="","",", "&N2)&IF(O2="","",", "&O2),1,2,"")`